# Assigning a template value to a class template via a pointer to its non-template parent class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I'm trying to make a C++ `Template` class that can store a template value.  However, I need to create pointers to this class before the type of the template value is known.  To do this, I created an abstract `Base` class that the template class inherits from.  I create pointers to `Base`, and when they are allocated, I use `basePtr = new Template<TYPE>`.

The problem here is in assigning a value to `Template`.  Every way I can think of to do so (I'd LIKE to use an overloaded assignment operator) requires a method with a template datatype as a formal parameter.  Because `Template` objects can only be accessed through `Base` pointers, I have to make a virtual function in `Base`.  However, virtual methods cannot contain template datatypes, and the virtual method in `Base`'s signature must match that of `Template`'s method.

Here's an example of what I'm going for:

```
class Base {
    public:
        /* THIS IS ILLEGAL - can't have template virtual method
        template <class V>
        virtual void operator =(const V& newValue) = 0;
        */
};

template <class ValueType>
class Template : public Base {
    private:
        ValueType *value;
    public:
        void operator =(const ValueType& newValue) {
            *value = newValue;
        }
};

int main() {
    Base *theObject;                  // Datatype for template not known 
    theObject = new Template<string>; // At this point, it will be known

    // NOW, THIS DOESN'T WORK - no virtual assignment overload in Base
    *theObject = "Hello, world!";

    return 0;
}
```

I apologize if I'm going about this the entirely wrong way, and if my method is stupid--this is my first foray into true OOD.  Is there a way around this problem that I'm not seeing?  I know I could create a long list of pure virtual functions in `Base` that overload the assignment operator with different input types, like so:

```
virtual void operator =(const string& newValue) = 0;
virtual void operator =(const int& newValue) = 0;
virtual void operator =(const long& newValue) = 0;
...
```

But, I want the user to be able to insert custom class objects (or, more likely, pointers to those objects) into `Template::value`, and I there's no way that can be done with the above methodology.

Comment: What would you like to happen when a value of an incompatible type is assigned to an object of your `Template<>` class? E.g. what should happen when I do `Base* pObj = new Template<int>(); *pObj = "Hello"`?

Comment: Ideally, `delete pObj; pObj = new Template<string>; *pObj = "Hello";`.  I haven't gotten to that point yet, when I need to start resetting the template datatypes for `Base` pointers, so I'm not entirely sure how I'll do it yet.  This is a part of a class that will store data in a table.  `Table` is composed of `Row`s, `Row`s are composed with `Cell`s, and `Template` is my cell object.

Comment: OK, but this assignment `*pObj = "Hello"` cannot do all that stuff. Is it OK if it throws an exception, so that the *client* code can do it?

Comment: It should be, to be honest I haven't gotten to exception handling in my studies.  It's ok if I can't use the assignment operator on a cell directly.  I could create a function in `Row` that takes an index of a cell and a new value to insert, and it will insert it in `cell[idx]`.

Comment: `Row` will contain a dynamic array of `Cell` pointers (`Base **cell`), and allocate the memory with `new` on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing what you are trying to achieve is to use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html) (a well-known header-only library). Below is a demonstration. The code is commented step-by-step, so you should be able to understand it, and **[here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/10CpDi%2467)** is a live example:

```
#include <stdexcept>       // Standard header for exception classes
#include <string>          // Standard header for std::string
#include <boost/any.hpp>   // The Boost.Any library header
#include <iostream>        // This program prints some output

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void operator = (boost::any val) = 0;
    //                       ^^^^^^^^^^
    //                       This can hold (almost) "any" value

    // You need a virtual destructor if you want to delete objects
    // of subclasses of this class through a pointer to this class!
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

template <class ValueType>
class Template : public Base
{
private:
    ValueType value;
//  ^^^^^^^^^
//  I do not see why using a pointer in this case. Manual memory
//  management just complicates things. However, if your really
//  need to do it and your really know what you're doing, go ahead.
//  Just remember to delete your pointer at destruction and not to
//  dereference it before it points to an allocated object (in your
//  original text, both of these things are NOT done correctly).
public:
    virtual void operator = (boost::any val)
    {
        // Attempt a cast to detect if the value we are trying to
        // assign to this object is of the appropriate type...
        ValueType* pVal = boost::any_cast<ValueType>(&val);
        if (pVal == nullptr)
        {
            // ...it is not! Throw an exception...
            throw std::logic_error("Incompatible type");
        }

        // The value is OK: assign it...
        value = *pVal;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *theObject;
    theObject = new Template<std::string>;

    try
    {
        // This assignment will succeed...
        // Wrapping the string literal in a std::string object is necessary
        // because boost::any cannot be initialized from an array (and in C++
        // string literals are arrays of characters).
        *theObject = std::string("Hello, world!");

        // This assignment will fail!
        *theObject = 1;
    }
    catch (std::logic_error const& e)
    {
        // Handle the exception...
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    delete theObject; // <=== DON'T FORGET THIS!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much.  At first glance, this looks like exactly what I'll need.  I'll have to take a closer look at Boost.Any and examine your well-documented code more carefully, but I think this might do it.  I want `Template::value` to be a pointer simply because I want to be able to save a pointer to an existing object, not just a copy of the object's data; that way, the client program can create data, put pointers to it in the table, modify the data, and those modifications will be reflected in the table.  Also, they could use the table [] overloads to access/modify its data.

Comment: I may make a separate `Template` class that handles pointers exclusively.  Otherwise, I'd need a `bool isPointer;` data member so the `Template` class will remember that it was passed a pointer--I wouldn't want to do a `delete value;` command in the `Template` destructor if it were.

Comment: @RichStarbuck: OK, consider using smart pointers then (`shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`). Normally, you want to avoid manual memory management through raw pointers. Anyway, if this will solve your problem or at least answer your questions and give you a good starting point, please consider accepting this answer :-)

Comment: I will definitely look into smart pointers, I haven't seen/heard of them before, but I'm always on the lookout for new technologies to learn.  I'm trying to figure out how to "accept" your answer, haven't seen it yet... Also, I apparently can't "+1" your answer until I receiver 15 reputations, and this is my first post.  Sorry :(

Comment: @RichStarbuck: That's fine, you can still accept the answer even if you cannot upvote it. But you don't need to do it now, just make sure it helps before.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like boost::any is somewhat what you are looking for.  No need for strange inheritance hierarchies, it can store arbitrary types (with certain restrictions) on its own.

Now what I'm concerned about is how you plan to get your value back out again?  How does your code figure out whether that cell contains an int, std::string, or some other user-defined type that it has never heard of before, short of attempting to any_cast it to some list of types (and what happens if the type isn't listed...)?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into boost::any right now, it looks like that's exactly what I need.  Come to think of it, getting the value back is going to be tricky.  So far, all I've done is output the value to cout with an overloaded << operator; I had to make a global (to the class.h file) operator overload that accepts a Base pointer, and calls baseObj->print(os); but, getting the value itself will be tougher.  One step at a time I suppose, right now I'm more concerned with getting the table of values generated.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need a returnValue() method in Template.  The return value for the Template method will be a `ValueType` (the template datatype for which Template is casted), but it's my understanding that return types don't affect the signature in terms of overloading, so I should be able to make a pure virtual function in Base that can be accessed through a Base pointer.

Comment: You could make a virtual function... but what are you going to declare it returning in the base class?  Because I presume you're going to call it through a Base* variable, which the compiler will enforce whatever type the Base has declared it returning.  You won't be able to use the ValueType version of it until you already know it's of the ValueType type.